# How can I use Selenium with Python to set the Chrome web driver device to iPhone products?

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-devtools

The following script uses Python 3.11 in conjunction with Selenium 4.9 to launch a Chrome driver (116.0.5845.96) simulating a Pixel 5 device.

```
from selenium import webdriver

mobile_emulation = {"deviceName": "Pixel 5"}
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option("mobileEmulation", mobile_emulation)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
print(driver.execute_script("return navigator.userAgent;"))

driver.get("https://youtube.com/")

input("Press Enter to continue...")
```

The standard out reports the following user agent:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 11; Pixel 5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.91 Mobile Safari/537.36
```

When I attempt to change it to `{"deviceName": "iPhone SE"}` the driver renders the mobile page but the user agent is reported as a Windows device:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/116.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
```

I was expecting something like `(iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 13_2_3 like Mac OS X)`; am I doing something wrong? I am aware that I can set a custom device but would like to use the predefined devices.